# How do I build boost universal libraries for x86 and x64 architecture?

Tags: c++, macos, boost, 64-bit

Like in the title : How do I build boost universal libraries for x86 and x64 architecture ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `architecture=combined` to build both Intel and PowerPC. Add `address-model=32_64` to build both x86 and x64 in one package. See [Apple Darwin gcc](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/reference/tools.html)

```
bjam toolset=darwin --with-... address-model=32_64 architecture=combined
```

Comment: `toolset`, `address-model`, and `architecture` are features, and thus must not have leading `--`s. I.e., that should be `bjam toolset=darwin --with-... address-model=32_64 architecture=combined`.

Comment: @ildjarn: thanks, fixed my post. I did not had my Mac handy to validate first, sry

Comment: @Remus : No worries, +1 now :-]